# TypeScript - prevent push object with only interface implements to array of object class instances

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

At default TS configurations I can create array of objects which is instances of some class.
But if I want to push to this array some objects which is only implementation of one of interfaces that is implemented by class - I dont get any error!

I explain my problem with code. Situation 4 is situation that I want to avoid

```
interface ICat {
  catName: string;
  meow: () => void;
}

class Cat implements ICat {
  catName: string;
  meow = () => {
    console.log("Meowww -", this.catName);
  };

  constructor(catName: string) {
    this.catName = catName;
  }

  getCatNameWithSound: () => void = () => {
    this.catName;
    this.meow();
  };
}

const catsNotInstancesOfClass: ICat[] = [];
const catsInstancesOfClass: Cat[] = [];

const cat1Instance = new Cat("Fufa");
const cat2Instance = new Cat("Puff");

const cat1NotInstance: ICat = {
  catName: "Fufa-NotInstance",
  meow: () => {
    console.log("Meowww -", this.catName);
  },
};

const cat2NotInstance: ICat = {
  catName: "Puff-NotInstance",
  meow: () => {
    console.log("Meowww -", this.catName);
  },
};

// Situation 1 - it is OK
// I can push instance of class Cat (which implements ICat interface) to array of objects implements ICat interface
catsNotInstancesOfClass.push(cat1Instance);
catsNotInstancesOfClass.push(cat2Instance);

// Situation 2 - it is OK
// I can push instance of class Cat to array of objects typeof Cat
catsInstancesOfClass.push(cat1Instance);
catsInstancesOfClass.push(cat2Instance);

/////////////////

// Situation 3 - it is OK
// I can push object thats implements ICat interface to array of object implements ICat interface
catsNotInstancesOfClass.push(cat1NotInstance);
catsNotInstancesOfClass.push(cat2NotInstance);

// !!! Situation 4 - it is NOT OK !
// I can push object thats implements ICat interface to array of objects type of Cat class instance... But ICat is not (!) instance of Cat! It does not have "getCatNameWithSound" method!
catsInstancesOfClass.push(cat1Instance);
catsInstancesOfClass.push(cat2Instance);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; your situation 4 is identical to situation 2.  Is this just a typo?  If you change the code to represent the situation you're talking about (try to push an `ICat` onto a `Cat[]`) you will get an error.

Comment: Ahh... Its only my fault... Sorry for for the confusion.

I have class and interface, but class has OPTIONAL fields, so interface fit the class.

In example you cant see it.

Thank you for your interest, but post can be closed :)